# Sencha Touch 2 Android local database performance

Tags: android, sqlite, sencha-touch-2

I'm currently working on a mobile app, I have a requirement to create local database for Android. Though I am using Sencha Touch 2 for development, I am worried for SQLite database from within the browser sandbox.

Which one is more reliable, allocates more memory and fast: SQLite database from within the browser sandbox Or Native SQLite database.
What are the differences in both?

I can use Native SQLite database using phone gap, But primarily I am confused which is better to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just using sencha's localstorage... It seems reasonably fast for me and works well with WebView...Also if you go for a native solution that only works in android then you would have to find a corresponding solution for iOS... Localstorage works in both platforms since it is linked to HTML5 and not to the native platforms...